# Force even clusters is sciki-learn Kmeans

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

Is there any way to force even cluster sizes with scikit-learn's [Kmeans implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.k_means.html)?

I'm using the default settings to cluster 100 documents into 2 clusters, but Kmeans puts 99 into one cluster. How do I force it to make an even 50/50 split? Or is this just a limitation of Kmeans?

Comment: `How do I force it to make an even 50/50 split?` - The standard definition learns the cluster assignment and the cluster sizes in parallel. In your case I suspect that the data does not have two clusters, or the cluster shape cannot be expressed by simple k-means. Forcing a 50/50 split will probably not help in this case as the clusters you will get will probably be meaningless.

Comment: @cei, There are plenty of papers describing versions of Kmeans that enforce even cluster sizes. I'm asking if this is implemented in scikit-learn.

Comment: I don't think so.